# New Zealand satellite imagery Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, mapping, imagery, satellite

I want to create a satellite image for all of New Zealand using 2020 Landsat 8 satellite imagery to then calculate NDVI to export into QGIS. I am wanting to compare to 1990 satellite imagery so want to keep it in one season i.e., summer. The issue I am running into is cloudy imagery. However, when I search USGS I can find a good series of cloud free images, I just can't seem to get them into GEE...

Here is my current code showing cloudy imagery -

```js
// Define the region of interest (New Zealand)
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[168.1, -47.2], [168.1, -34.4], [178.6, -34.4], [178.6, -47.2]]);

// Define the time range
var startDate = '2018-08-01';
var endDate = '2018-12-31';

// Load Landsat 8 surface reflectance data
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

// Function to mask clouds using the pixel_qa band
function maskClouds(image) {
  var pixel_qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Create a mask to exclude clouds (value 1) and shadows (value 2)
  var mask = pixel_qa.bitwiseAnd(1).eq(0).and(pixel_qa.bitwiseAnd(2).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

// Apply cloud masking function to the collection
var collectionMasked = collection.map(maskClouds);

// Select bands for visualization (true color)
var visParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};

// Add the imagery to the map
Map.addLayer(collectionMasked, visParams, 'Landsat 8 RGB');

// Center the map on the region of interest
Map.centerObject(roi, 6);
```

Comment: Are they T1 SR images?  Got a sample ID that doesn't exist in EE?  Also, don't use C1; it's going to go away soon.  Use C2.

Comment: Try setting the bit values as `1 << 1` and `1 << 2` instead of `1` and `2`, to see if that helps.